# Problems with phpmyadmin

Tags: localhost, phpmyadmin, wampserver, wamp

I already worked a lot with wampserver but it's the first time i have a problem with it.

After I downloaded it wanted to create a database in phpmyadmin, and then it says:

> "Forbidden. You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this
>   server."

Can somebody help me because this is really strange and I need a database for my program ^^.

Answer (score 2):

It could be a number of things but it is probably that apache is Listening on the W8 IPV6 default localhost address which is ::1

1. edit httpd.conf, using the link on the wampserver icon wampserver -> apache -> https.conf
   find the line > Listen 80
   and change to > listen 0.0.0.0:80

This will force apache to listen on IPV4 and make the pre-configured phpMyAdmin security configuration compatable.

By default phpMyAdmin has the following access restriction:
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1

IP Address 127.0.0.1 is the IPv4 address for localhost

You may also need to make sure your HOSTS file has the line

## 127.0.0.1 localhost

uncommented to
127.0.0.1 localhost
or add it if it does not exists.

The hosts file is protected by windows, in order to save it you must have Administrator privilages.
Vista/W7/W8 you may think you are an Administrator BUT YOU ARE NOT.

To successfully save the hosts file do this to launch your editor with Admin Privilages.

Locate your editors icon on the desktop or from the Start menus ( notepad will do if you have nothing else )
left click + shift over your chosen editor icon - will show a menu.
select "Run As Administrator" from the menu.
Navigate your editor to the c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file.

When you have made changes you will now be allowed to save them.

Comment: I did step 1 correctly,
In my HOSTS there are 4 time "127.0.0.1 localhost" and 1 time "::1 localhost" Is that normal?
I just dont get the step to save it. Do i need to make a shortcut or just cut the HOSTS file out and paste it on my desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Your phpmyadmin configuration file contents in wamp alias folder must look as below:

```
     <Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride all
         Order Deny,Allow
         Allow from all
     </Directory>
```

Whereas it looks as this:

```
     <Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.4.5/">
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride all
         Order Deny,Allow
         Deny from all
         Allow from 127.0.0.1
     </Directory>
```

The same can be used to make your "sqlbuddy" and "webgrind" applications to work.